# Sometimes throw NullPointerException, and sometimes not. How to fix?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, collision-detection

Here's an excerpt of the init of the object:

```
    ...
            Rectangle b1 = tenBullets.getBounds();
    ...
```

Here's the getBounds() method:

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, 200, 25);
}
```

And here is the console message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at test.game.Board.checkCollisions(Board.java:75)
at test.game.Board.actionPerformed(Board.java:53)
at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Board.java:75 is when the getBounds() method is called. Sometimes the exception is thrown, and 1 out of the 10th time it's not. Any fixes?

Comment: If line 75 is `tenBullets.getBounds()`, then `tenBullets` is null for some reason, wihch we can't guess because you have not shown the relevant code (= where you initialize that variable).

Comment: You could check the value of tenBullets, probably using some kind of logger

Comment: @user1496383 any other calls that use tenBullets between that and the line 75? Any try / catch block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NullPointerException` is thrown because `tenBullets` is `null` when that method is called - and you're trying to invoke a method on a null object (which isn't possible, and leads to the exception).

In order to fix this, you need to do one of two things:

1. Change the preceding behaviour, so that `tenBullets` is always assigned a value before you call `getBounds()` on it.  This is the option to choose is `tenBullets` should *never* be null at this point.
2. Make the code in the question tolerant of null - check `if (tenBullets == null)`, and take some alternative action if this is true.  This is the option to choose if null might well be a sensible value (perhaps it may or may not be initialised); if so, you have to deal with that eventuality.

Without understanding either the intent or the context of the code, it's impossible to give concrete recommendations.  However, if `tenBullets` is a field (as opposed to a local variable), consider whether it *ever* makes sense for it to be unset (or modified); and if not, declare it `final`.  This will guarantee that it is initialised within the constructor and holds that value consistently.

In general, reducing the number of mutable fields/variables makes it much easier to reason about a program, because you need to be less aware of what state it may or may not be in at the time of execution.  It sounds like that's your problem here, that `tenBullets` is being assigned by some other bit of code, at some point, and there's no definitive ordering.

Comment: Thank you for quick respons! I declared it as a global final object - and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have shown, I cannot say for sure, but sometimes I get inconsistencies in Eclipse, when i rename files and code snippets. Even though everything is correct, Eclipse has cached some old names, that may conflict.

To resolve this, go to project -> clean and remove all compiled files.

Again, not sure if this is your problem here, but I've seen it before